# Facebook Graph API Search public events based on location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I am trying to implement the event search based on the location.

I can get the events list by using:

```
/search?q=someevent&type=event
```

But not sure how to get the events belong to a location.

I have tried below:

```
/search?q=someevent&type=event&center=12.9539974,77.6309395&distance=1000
```

seems this is not working.

Please let me know what is the other option to get the events belong to a specific location

Answer (score 1):

I don´t think you can do that, you can only search for an event OR a location/place. You could search for a place (by name and location), check if it´s connected to a page and request all the events from that page with an extra API call.